# Importing virtual disk on GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vmdk

I have transformed a VMDK disk of a Ubuntu 16.04 host into a raw image using `qemu-img convert`. Everything seems fine, I can mount it and check its contents. I uploaded it to a GCS bucket, following the instructions.

However, it doesn't seem to boot, so I'm following [these](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks#making_an_image_bootable) official instructions to make that image bootable.

The conversion job always fails with this message:

```
[import-from-image.translate-disk.translate-disk.wait-for-translator]: 2018-10-08T12:42:49Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-translator-import-from-image-translate-disk-transla-95yyp": watching serial port 1, SuccessMatch: "TranslateSuccess:", FailureMatch: "TranslateFailed:".
[import-from-image]: 2018-10-08T12:45:19Z Error running workflow: step "translate-disk" run error: step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-import-from-image-translate-disk-transla-95yyp": "TranslateFailed: error: sh: E: Package 'cloud-init' has no installation candidate"
[import-from-image]: 2018-10-08T12:45:19Z Workflow "import-from-image" cleaning up (this may take up to 2 minutes).
[Daisy] Errors in one or more workflows:
import-from-image: step "translate-disk" run error: step "translate-disk" run error: step "wait-for-translator" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-translator-import-from-image-translate-disk-transla-95yyp": "TranslateFailed: error: sh: E: Package 'cloud-init' has no installation candidate"
```

Has anyone seen this `Package 'cloud-init' has no installation candidate` error?

Comment: I haven't seen the error. But, have you tried to use this [tool](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/tree/master/cli_tools/import_precheck/) to check for incompatibilities before the conversion/migration? And the limitations per this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks#limitations). It also seems to me that a conversion from vmdk is not needed per the same document.

Comment: Not related, but, you can also try the same exact method manually using Daisy from a Compute Engine instance per this [github](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/compute-image-tools/image-import.html) rather than using the gcloud command.

Answer (score 0):

install [cloud-init](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-init) before trying to convert - then it won't need installation candidates.

this means, boot the `vmdk` and then run `sudo apt-get cloud-init`.